# Determine radicals for simplifed characters that lost their traditional form completely

Tags: radicals, simplified-characters, traditional-characters

Having read this question: [How can one determine the radical for a given character?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/215/how-can-one-determine-the-radical-for-a-given-character),
it gave me another question.

Since many simplified characters lost their original form (compared to traditional ones), how do I actually look up their radicals? A classical example would be "leaf". In traditional form, it's 葉 whereas it's 叶 in simplified form. The traditional form preserved the 艹 (艸) radical (which means grass), but simplified form does not have it at all. Just by looking at 叶, you'd think it has 口 as radical, but 口 (mouth) has nothing to do with leaf...

If anyone can think of examples similar to this, please share.

Comment: You can determine its radical as you determine the radical of other character.The radical of “叶" is “口". I think you really concern "why 口 is used for 叶,while 口 has nothing to do with the leaf？", if so, you may propose a new question.

Comment: There's also traditional 話 and simplified 话. The radical changes.

Comment: may I start a new thread to explain how some characters are simplified and why there are criticisms on the simplification.

Comment: @Huang Thanks for your comment, and I guess you're probably right - I was puzzled by the fact that 叶 has no association with 葉 and tree leaves. I'll start a new question and you can answer it. I look forward to your explanation :)

Answer (score 10):

The radical of many simplified characters has nothing to do with the character itself; the only reason for this is just to simplify characters. I have some examples (found on the web):

[image]

> 1) Without the **heart**, how can one *love*
>
> 2) Looking back at the *hometown*, the **man** has already left
>
> 3) No *morals*, because it is none of **my** business
>
> 4) The *leader* has lost his/her **path**
>
> 5) Unable to **see** each other, how can the two *be close(intimate)*?

Comment: I edited your image because it was too big. This fits better. If you think the quality is too poor (it was before too for the small characters), you can make a simple table in some program like I structured it (more horizontal than vertical) and post it here as an image. :)

Comment: Can someone translate the comments below the characters on the image for us noobs?

Comment: God... this picture reminds me of some stupid conversations I've had with Taiwanese people. I'm not a great fan of the way Character simplification turned out, but it's **not** because ``爱`` doesn't have a heart (or, worse yet, 义 no longer depicts [the sacrifice of a sheep](http://chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?submitButton1=Etymology&characterInput=%E4%B9%89). the horror!)