# How are dictionaries of ideograms sorted?

Tags: dictionary

Since Chinese. Japanese and Korean have no alphabetical writing system how do those people sort their dictionaries?

Comment: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/135/how-to-find-characters-in-a-dictionary?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_dictionary)

> The second system of dictionary organization is by recurring graphic
> components or radicals. (...) As most
> Chinese characters are semantic-phonetic ones (形聲字), the radical
> method is usually effective, thus it continues to be widely used in
> the present day. However, sometimes the radical of a character is not
> obvious. To compensate this, a "Chart of Characters that Are Difficult
> to Look up" (難檢字表), arranged by the number of strokes of the
> characters, is usually provided.

Here is what a chart of radicals in a dictionary looks like

[image]

- You can otherwise search a character by its pinyin if you know it.

See also: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-look-up-Chinese-characters-in-a-Chinese-dictionary

Comment: Thank you, my question was moved from the Language Learning forum, so I decided to generalize my question. Now I think it belongs back to the first forum again. I you know someone who can move it back that would be great.

Comment: @Demis Please don't change a question after an answer has been provided. Minor edits such as typos and clarifications are OK, but moving the goalposts is not.